# A proof that parallel transport preserves orientation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a riemannian manifold (With the Levi-Civita connection), $c$ a curve in $M$ with $c(t_0)=c_0,c(t)=c_t$ $P_{c,t_0,t}$ denote the function $T_{c_0}M\to T_{c_t}M$ given by parallel transporting each tangent vector $v\in T_{c_0}M$ to $T_{c_t}M$ along the curve $c$.

I want to prove that $P=P_{c,t_0,t}$ is an isometry which preserves orientation, given that $M$ is orientable.

I've already proven that it's an isometry and its inverse is given by $P_{c,t,t_0}$. I now want to prove, that, with the orientation induced by
$\phi_t:\mathbb{R}^n\to T_{c_t}M$ with $\phi_t(e_i)=\partial_{i,c_t}$ the orientation is preserved. In other words, the mapping $P':T_{c_t}M\to T_{c_t}M$ given by $\partial_{i,c_t}\mapsto P_{c,t_0,t}\partial_{i,c_0}$ has positive determinant with respect to those bases.

Since it's an isometry, then its determinant is $\pm 1$, so I just have to prove it's $1$.

If the function $d:\text{dom} c\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $t\mapsto \det P'$ is continuous, then since $d(t_0)=1$, if $d(t_1)=-1$ there would be some $t\in (t_0,t_1)$ such that $d(t)=0$ and this is impossible.

So the only thing left is to prove that $d$ is continuous. How could I do that?

---

An idea would be, that this function can be seen as a composition of continuous functions:

$t_0\stackrel{V}{\to} V_{c(t_0)}\stackrel{P}{\to} V_{c(t)}\stackrel{?}{\to}d(t_0)$
but I'm not sure what would go in ?.

Comment: Consider parallel transport along the center curve of a Moebius band.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a condition for $M$ to be orientable.

Comment: If your definition of "orientable" is "there exists a non-vanishing form $\eta$ of top degree", you could fix an orthonormal frame $E_{0}$ at $c(t_{0})$, let $E_{t}$ be the orthonormal frame at $c(t)$ obtained by parallel transport along $c$, and show the function $f(t) = \eta(E_{t})$ is continuous and non-vanishing.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang What would happen if my definition of orientable is that, for all the elements of the atlas, the transition functions have jacobian greater than $0$?

Comment: If you work in a coordinate chart, the orthonormal frame bundle (whose fibre over a point $p$ consists of all orthonormal frames in $T_{p}M$) is trivial and has two path components, one for each choice of orientation. Parallel transport of $E$ along $c$ may be viewed as a continuous lift of $c$ into the frame bundle. (This is fancy talk for a fairly simple idea that can certainly be explained without saying "frame bundle"; not sure how many technical tools you've encountered.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Formally we have not seen anything about the concept "Frame bundle", and not about vector bundles or locally trivial bundles, nonethless, I get the idea (I have read a bit about vector bundles in other books).

We're following the Do Carmo book on Riemannian Geometry, and there it says something about the "Volume form", which seems to be related to the orientation, but we haven't seen that relation. In fact the book introduces Riemannian metrics with the least theory I've seen in all the books I've started to use.

Comment: It is straightforward to show that parallel transport of a frame along a curve within a connected coordinate chart preserves orientation. Any curve in the manifold is an overlapping union of curves, where each lies in a single coordinate chart. The positive Jacobian insures that the orientation does not change as the curve moves from one coordinate chart to another.

Comment: nice...............   +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_i^0\}$  be an orthonormal basis for $T_{c(t_0)}M$.  Let  $(U,\phi)$ be a chart about $c(t)$. Define $\det:TU \times TU \times \dots \times TU \longrightarrow \mathbb R $   by
$$(u_1,\dots,u_n)\mapsto \det(u_1, \dots u_n) = \det( a_{ij}) $$
where $  u_j = \sum^n_{i=1} a_{ij} e_i  $. This function is continuous . Let $V_i(t)$ be the parallel transport of $e_i^0$ to $T_{c(t)}M$ which is continuous.  So we have the following diagram of the continuous  function a
$$(t_0,t_1) \xrightarrow{V=(V_1,V_2,\dots,V_n)}  TU \times TU \times \dots \times TU \xrightarrow{\text{det}} \mathbb R. $$
Since   vectors   $ V_j(t)= \sum^n_{i=1} a_{ij}(t)e_i^t $ are linearly independent $ \zeta(t) = (\det (V(t)) \neq 0$. And since $\zeta$ is continuous if we choose $\{e_i^0\}$ such that $\zeta(0) >0$  it will remain so for every $t$. The results follows from this.